# How to remove the status bar on the tableview

Tags: ios7, tableview, status

I have a problem with the status bar.

I wonder if it Were possible to remove the status bar only for my tableView and keep for the rest of the application?

Cordialy

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the appropriate place, we don't know what your code looks like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```